# Programmatically set the format for each value of a multi-value text field

Tags: 8

I am trying to programmatically set the format of a multi value text field to 'full_html'.

**I have tried:**

```
$Links = array (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

$node->field_article_links[] = $Links;
$node->field_article_links->format = 'full_html';
$node->save();
```

and

```
$Links = array (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

foreach ($Links as $Link) {
$node->set('field_article_links', $Link);
$node->field_article_links->format = 'full_html';
}
$node->save();
```

But the results are always the same, only the **format** of the first value of the field is set to 'full_html' and the others remain unchanged.

[image: node edit]

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Where did you put your code which hook?

Comment: check this out https://www.berramou.com/blog/drupal-8-how-set-default-format-textformat-and-hide-select-programmatically

Comment: @berramou my code is in a custom handler for webform using `public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please, do not start with capital letter when naming variables, every time you do that a puppy dies.**

As 'field_article_links' can have more than one value (probably is a unlimited field), you should treat its value as an array and not as single entity, where each element has its value and format.

To do that, you have to build an array with the field data, then put this array into the field.

The following code is working as you expect:

```
$links = array (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);    
$field_data = [];
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $element = [];
    $element['value'] = $link;
    if($link === 3) {
        $element['format'] = 'full_html';
    } else {
        $element['format'] = 'dasdas';
    }
    $field_data[] = $element;
}
$node->field_article_links = $field_data;
$node->save();
```

[image]

Comment: You saved my hours, thank you for your help ! Working as expected

Comment: **Please, do not start with capital letter when naming variables, every time you do that a puppy dies.**
Can you please explain what is the downside of using capital while naming variables because i do this with every single variable.

Comment: Regarding to the naming variables conventions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming).

It is about standards, if we all write with the same rules, reading and understanding other's code will be easy and fast.

Comment: Other programming languages like Python, Java or .Net have stronger naming rules and you are not allowed to start a variable with a capital letter since it will throw compile errors.